# Google Device verification API not working

Tags: android, kotlin, google-api

I'm working on google verification api with `minifyEnabled=true`, and proguard always use `CtsProfileMatch=false` and `basicIntegrity=false`.

With this, it is not working even for valid devices.
With out proguard it is working fine.

what should I enter in proguard file?

plz help thank u in advance

Comment: -keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/tasks-android-sample/proguard-google-api-client.txt

Comment: @UsamaAltaf - Tried but not working...we r using safetynet api